# Exception when I run application @FXML bind with Controller

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I added tag @FXML and in SceneBuilder added fx:id in textfield on userid, passwordfield on userpassword.
**loginController**

```
@FXML
private TextField userid;
@FXML
private PasswordField userpassword;
```

And output when I start application:

```
Executing /home/wolacinio/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Jva/Marks/dist/run141945473/Marks.jar using platform /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/home/wolacinio/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Jva/Marks/dist/run141945473/Marks.jar!/marks/login.fxml:27

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at marks.Marks.start(Marks.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javafx.scene.control.PasswordField field marks.loginController.userpassword to javafx.scene.control.TextField
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1163)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$1600(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:857)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:751)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application marks.Marks
Java Result: 1
```

[loginController.java](http://pastebin.com/Pbi1tc09) and [login.fxml](http://pastebin.com/2aqG882C)
It seems to me everything looks good. What's the problem?

Comment: THis is your error : Can not set javafx.scene.control.PasswordField field marks.loginController.userpassword to javafx.scene.control.TextField.

Can you show us your FXML code as well as any other Java Code?  It seems like you're trying to set your PasswordField to a TextField...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2aqG882C and http://pastebin.com/Pbi1tc09

Comment: please add to your actual question please, thanks.

Comment: The ids in your fxml-controls are wrong. Set fx:id="userid" for your TextField and fx:id="userpassword" in your PasswordField. Then ist should work. And update your question as Lasagna asked :)

Comment: Thanks so much. It was wrong fx:id in FXML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javafx.scene.control.PasswordField field marks.loginController.userpassword to javafx.scene.control.TextField
```

In your controller you have mentioned the userpassword as PasswordField where as in FXML it is declared as

```
 <TextField fx:id="userpassword" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
```

While mapping both should be of same type or you will get the same exception.

Thanks